# VBA challenge: Spent a while with VBA, just messing this up more

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm in a rush to put together an excel file for something quick and dirty at work. I've spent several days learning VBA / macros and have learned many individual pieces needed for this, but putting them all together is just not working how I'm looking for.

So I'm taking something similar to the following table of data and trying to reorganize it:

(I can't post the image bc of rep)

![Sample Data Table] https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDGC5.jpg

Data in columns d-f are all a list of stuff. What I want to do is start with the first date in column D, find the range of where it fits in column a and copy the data there. For an expense report for example - e1:f1 data would get copied over to b1:c1 since it corresponds with that as the date range. In a nutshell, dates in column A are income dates. They are set to pay all items listed on the right scheduled to be paid before the next pay date. See the finished example here:

![Final Sample Data Table] https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE22W.jpg

How might you throw this together to make it work. I'm looking for simplicity as I'm gonna have to heavily modify it to what its actually being applied to.

Sorry for the weird post, this is my first time creating a post myself :)

Comment: you forgot to ask a question and you forgot to show some work.

Answer (score 0):

A handy way to get started with VBA is to [record a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) of the actions you need to duplicate, and then [analyze the macro's generated VBA code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx), line by line, [revising the code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros) to fit your needs.

(Also: [Using Comparison Operators in VBA](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vba%20comparison%20operators%20examples))

Comment: True. And I now have about 3 dozen of these. Problem is, they don't know logic in the sense that the human mind does. A recorded macro can't (that I'm aware of) look at two different cells and know that this box belongs between the two. If-statements etc.

Comment: That's where the revising the code part comes in.  Record an example (with the human mind making the comparison) and then you'll have all the code you need except for one line to automate the decision.  Perhaps a look at [using comparison operators](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vba+comparison+operators+examples) in VBA will shed some light.